# Reading Data via Api for app from table without entity/definition

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

I need to read data from the table cart for my app. But an api/search/ call wouldn't work, I think, because cart has no entity/definition. SQL is not possible via the api or in scripts as far as I know.
So, is there a way to get these data?

I do not know what to try because I am afraid it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is intended that you should not access the cart table via the database abstraction, hence why there is no entity definition and repository for it. In fact it is to discourage altering data sets in the cart table entirely. You'd run the risk of violating the business logic by altering the table entries, when there are multiple collectors and processors relying on the integrity of the tables content.

If you want to alter the cart [you should use the cart service inside app scripts](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts/cart-manipulation) instead.

Comment: I only wanted to read the cart table, not to change it, for statistical reasons.

Comment: Same principle. That's what the collectors are for. By reading from the table directly you circumvent an entire set of business logic.